# Is there a way for CSS to interpret `start` and/or `value` properties of `ol` and `li` tags for custom alpha counters?

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-counter

I'm converting a site with thousands of pages to use CSS counters instead of the standard HTML list presentation. The nature of the project makes it significantly easier to alter the CSS rather than the HTML. The site uses many different kinds of lists, and some of them use the `start` property at the `ol` level and/or the `value` property at the `li` level to continue previous lists and/or skip values.

So far I've been able to target the different lists successfully and give them all the custom list styles I want, and even change the counters in the `:before` contents of numbered lists using `attr(start)` and `attr(value)`. What I still can't figure out is how to translate those numeric values into letters when I need a lettered list to start somewhere besides `a` or skip a value.

```html
<ol class="lower-alpha" start="2">
    <li>Explain...</li>
    <li>Describe...</li>
    <li value="5">Calculate...</li>
</ol>
```

```css
ol.lower-alpha {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: special-little-letters;
    & > li { 
        list-style: none;
        &:before {
            content: counter(special-little-letters,lower-alpha);
        }
        counter-increment: special-little-letters;
    }
    &[start] { 
        counter-reset: special-little-letters attr(start); /* doesn't work */
    }
    & > li[value]:before {
        counter-reset: special-little-letters attr(value); /* doesn't work */
        content: counter(special-little-letters,lower-alpha)
    }
}
```

I want a lettered list that goes `b`, `c`, `e`. I get `a`, `b`, `c`, and an error "Invalid property value" when inspecting the results.

Comment: this can probably give you a good workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55201090/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your answer there would require me to add `style="--start:6"` throughout my HTML and has nothing for `li value`. My goal is to avoid alterations to HTML and handle both `ol start` and `li value`.

Comment: Like I did for start you can do it for value by using another CSS variable

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't change the HTML, though.

Comment: It remains a possible workaround in case someone face the same issue and can alse change the HTML.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm happy any person with that similar issue will have a link to your answer as it seems clever. Personally, if I could change the HTML I would just add the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` styles and leave the CSS what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the counter to start from `b`, you'll need to increment the counter on `ol.lower-alpha`. Then if you want to skip `d` for the `value` attribute, you simply need to call `counter-increment` again in `ol.lower-alpha>li[value]:before`.

Also note that applying an attribute to `counter-reset` is invalid syntax, so you won't see that rule taking effect. I've removed it from my following example.

```css
ol.lower-alpha {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: special-little-letters;
  counter-increment: special-little-letters;
}

ol.lower-alpha>li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: special-little-letters;
}

ol.lower-alpha>li:before {
  content: counter(special-little-letters, lower-alpha);
}

ol.lower-alpha[start] {
  counter-reset: special-little-letters;
}

ol.lower-alpha>li[value]:before {
  counter-increment: special-little-letters;
}
```

```html
<ol class="lower-alpha" start="2">
  <li>Explain...</li>
  <li>Describe...</li>
  <li value="5">Calculate...</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This makes all `ol` with class `lower-alpha` start with `b` and causes `li` with any `value` to skip 1. I'm asking if different values for `start` and `value` can result in corresponding letters, like they do for HTML.

Comment: Put another way, I don't "want the counter to start from `b`". I want the counter to start from the letter that corresponds with the `start` value in any `<ol>` tag (and skip to the letter that corresponds with the `value` value in any `<li>` tag).